# Как возможно реализовать чекер незанятых юзернеймов в телеграмме?

Tags: python, telegram

Нужно сделать чекер незанятых юзернеймов в телеграмме. Если использовать Telethon и pyrogram, то будет неточность (если ник некорректный, то будет писать что он свободен) + флуд бан на час/ сутки. Запрос по ссылке "t.me/..." не работает, т.к. даже если человека с таким юзернеймом не существует, то все равно будет кнопка, чтобы написать ему (ника может не быть, но юзернейм все равно занят). Пробовал через селениум в настройках вводить ник и чекать сообщение, но после 200 попыток будет выводить, что ник занят, даже если он свободен. Так же писал @username_bot и кидал ему ники, там уже работает телеграмм флуд защита и сообщения перестают отправляться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы решить данную проблему нужно использовать библиотеку Telethon и два метода: client.get_entity() и client(functions.account.CheckUsernameRequest), так же для того чтобы избежать Floodwaiterror нужно использовать более 10 аккаунтов и чередовать их.

https://github.com/krazzu/telegram_username_checker --- Здесь реализован мой способ